# jLync and Lync Web App poor video quality

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, lync, lync-client-sdk

So this question was asked here, but no answer was given. I am using microsoft jLync and the Lync Web App plugin in order to get a video call from one computer to another.

The issue is that the video quality becomes awful when I set the size to be 360x360 px. Its not that big but the quality is really grainy. Has anyone had this issue before or know how to improve the video quality?

I am using version 0.0.3 for both jLync and the LWE plugin.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

jLync (which is no longer the current name for the framework) is under NDA and not publicly available, so you may not get any responses here. You should post this to the specific Microsoft Connect forums for this product, the guys there will help out.